Eigenvalues of product of two stochastic matrices
Dear StackExchange Community,
during my research I constructed an algorithm, which compute a special kind of matrix. Let's call the matrix $A$. All matrices in this post are square matrices have just real entries and have the same size. The last step of computing is, that
$A:=L\cdot R$
I know about $L$ the following:

$L$ is row stochastic.
$L$ is non negative.
$L$ is a lower triangular matrix
$L$ has a spectrum of $1,\ldots,1,0.5,\ldots, 0.5 > \lambda_i>0$ (this means, that it has a lot of eigenvalues equal to 1, a lot of eigenvalues equal to 0.5 and all other eigenvalues are between 0.5 and 0 and real).
The diagonal of $L$ is $?,\ldots,?,0.5,\ldots,0.5,1$.

I know about $R$ the following:

$R$ is row stochastic.
$R$ is non negative.
$R$ is a upper triangular matrix
$R$ has a spectrum of $1,0.5,\ldots, 0.5 > \lambda_i>0$ (this means, that it has exactly one eigenvalues equal to 1, a lot of eigenvalues equal to 0.5 and all other eigenvalues are between 0.5 and 0 and real).
The diagonal of $R$ is $1,\ldots,1,0.5,\ldots,0.5,?,\ldots ?$.

Moreover in the diagonal of $L$ and $R$ there do not overlap the 1 and 0.5 part, so if $L_{i,i}= 1$ or $=0.5$ then $R_{i,i}=?$ and vice versa.
I also know (due to the property of stochastic matrices) that
$A\cdot 1=1,\quad L\cdot 1=1\quad $ and $\quad R\cdot 1=1$,
so 1 is an eigenvalue of $A,L,R$ to the eigenvector $1$. Furthermore I know by construction of the matrix $L,R$ and $A$, that there are three vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ such that
$R\cdot [v_1,v_2,v_3]= 0.5 [v_1,v_2,v_3], \quad  L\cdot [v_1,v_2,v_3]=  [v_1,v_2,v_3] \quad $ and so $ \quad A\cdot [v_1,v_2,v_3]= 0.5 [v_1,v_2,v_3]$
by construction of the matrix. The numerical results of over 300k random examples yield, that the spectrum of $A$ is real and
$1, 0.5,0.5,0.5 >\lambda_i>0$.
So I would like to proof the following properties (in order of importance, 1 is the most important fact):

$|\lambda_i|<0.5$
$\lambda_i $ is real
$\lambda_i $ is real and >0

I now would like to proof the upper relation but I do not know, how. I read a lot of theorems about eigenvalues of matrices, but there are not so many about the eigenvalues of the product of two matrices. Maybe there is something I just do not see? I would be really happy to any idea, reference ore commend.
Best Regards,
Alex

Here's a counterexample to your conjectures. It's based on the ideas user1551 used to construct this example.  Unlike that example, however, the $\ L\ $ and  $\ R\ $ in this one satisfy all the conditions specified in your question.
$$
L=\pmatrix{1\\
0&1\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{2}}
$$
$$
R=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&&&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}&\frac{1}{14}\\
&&&&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12}\\
&&&&&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{10}\\
&&&&&&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{8}\\
&&&&&&&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}\\
&&&&&&&&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}\\
&&&&&&&&&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
&&&&&&&&&&1}
$$
Both $\ L\ $ and $\ R\ $ are (row) stochastic matrices with eigenvalues $\ 1\ $ and $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ of multiplicities $\ 4\ $ and $\ 7\ $ respectively for $\ L\ $, and multiplicities $\ 1\ $ and $\ 10\ $ respectively for $\ R\ .$ If $\ v_1,v_2,v_ 3\ $ are the first three columns of the $\ 11\times11\ $ identity matrix, then
\begin{align}
R\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}&=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}\ \ \text{ and}\\
L\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, $\ L\ $ and $\ R\ $ satisfy all the conditions specified in your question.  However the spectrum of $\ A=LR\ $ is
\begin{align}
&1,0.5232,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.3348,0.2362,\\
&0.1982\pm0.006900i,0.19360\pm0.002765i\ .
\end{align}
Thus, for this example, none of the conditions you conjecture to be true of the matrix $\ A\ $ are satisfied:

There is one eigenvalue, $\ \lambda\approx0.5232\ $, with $\ 0.5<|\lambda|<1\ $; and
There are two pairs of complex conjugate eigenvalues. Though their imaginary parts are small in magnitude, they aren't zero.

Thus it looks like user1551 is correct in surmising that the matrices you constructed in your numerical experiments are  likely to have had some other properties you have yet to identify.

Dear Lonza Leggiera,
thanks for your reply! To know, that the reason must be somewhere deeper is very useful for me. I will have a look to the algorihm and the steps to compute the matrices $L$ and $R$. Maybe afterwards, I will write a new post with additional information and properties about the matrices.

(This is a long comment.) Either some properties of $L$ and/or $R$ have yet to be specified or you have made some mistakes in your numerical experiment. E.g. if you pick $L$ and $R$ at random, they almost never share any eigenvector, not to say a three-dimensional eigenspace. Even in case they do, $A$ seldom has a real spectrum. E.g. when
$$
L=\pmatrix{
1\\
\frac12&\frac12\\
\frac14&\frac14&\frac12\\ 0&0&0&1\\ \frac18&\frac18&\frac18&\frac18&\frac12\\ \frac18&\frac18&\frac18&\frac18&0&\frac12\\ \frac18&\frac18&\frac18&\frac18&0&0&\frac12\\ \frac18&\frac18&\frac18&\frac18&0&0&0&\frac12},\quad
R=\pmatrix{
\frac12&\frac18&\frac18&\frac18&0&0&0&\frac18\\
&\frac12&\frac16&\frac16&0&0&0&\frac16\\
&&\frac12&\frac14&0&0&0&\frac14\\
&&&\frac12&0&0&0&\frac12\\
&&&&\frac12&0&0&\frac12\\
&&&&&\frac12&0&\frac12\\
&&&&&&\frac12&\frac12\\
&&&&&&&1},
$$
$A=LR$ has a conjugate pair of non-real eigenvalues $0.3088 \pm 0.0431i$.

Dear user1551,
thanks for your reply. It is as lonza leggiera says. The matrices $A,L,R$ have the property of the common three-dimensional eigenspace by construction. So they are "special" matrices and not totally random. The construction of them would fill a lot of pages, so I tried just to decribe the facts, which I know about the matrices. It is also a good answer to know, that the upper properties are not enough to show, the upper statement. Then the reason might be somewhere deeper in the construction (or is simply wrong). I concreted the facts about the matrices in the original post.
